# converting rows into columns string builder

Tags: c#, string, pivot

I have a table to be included in mail as following:
(I get the data from view(.cshtml))

```
public ActionResult SendForApproveTimesheet(List<TimesheetMatrix> timesheetmatrixList) {
    int n = 1;
    timsheetMail = timsheetMail + " <table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" border=\"1\"><tr><td> Date </td><td> Working Hours </td><td> Task </td><td>Comments</td></tr>"; 
    foreach (TimesheetMatrix matrix in timesheetmatrixList) {           
        if ((timesheetData.Hours != Convert.ToDecimal(0.00)) && (timesheetData.Hours.HasValue == true)) {
            timsheetMail = timsheetMail + " <tr><td> " + timesheetData.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "</td><td>" + timesheetData.Hours + "</td><td>" + task + "</td><td>" + timesheetData.Notes +  "</td></tr>";                   
    }
    n++;
}
```

I have included this in mail as following :

```
 mailObj.Body = "Emp Name : " + EmpName + "<br /><br >" + Environment.NewLine + timsheetMail;
```

Now it include in mail as following :

```
Date        Working Hrs    Task                    Comments
08-02-2016  8            Testing        whole application testd
09-02-2016  8          Development        Client Requirments
10-02-2016  8          Installation      Install the app
11-02-2016  8             Design        New design
12-02-2016  8                 DB            db update
```

But i want to change this as following :

```
              08-02-2016       09-02-2016   10-02-2016  11-02-2016  12-02-2016
Testing         8       
Development                     8       
Installation                                    8   
Design                                                     8    
DB                                                                      8
```

Thats of changing my table using Pivot.. 
How can i do this..
Can anyone help me to do this..
Thanks in advance....

Comment: you should also post your stored procedure and table structure.

Comment: I get the data from view(.cshtml) and update the code.. please check it

Comment: what i mean that you can use pivot in your stored procedure then the data is sent to your view. Here in your view you only have to show it.

Comment: here i dont use stored procedure. I get the value from view in a list format.. from that list i have to send mail with my mentioned format table

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you should try the following code, I think it should be useful for your desired need.

```
   StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (DataRow rows in results.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
       foreach (DataColumn col in results.Tables[0].Columns)
       {
          output.AppendFormat("{0} ", rows[col]);
       }
       output.AppendLine();
   }
```